# Construct an explicit deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$ onto $S^{n−1}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

Just getting started with Hatcher, wondering if I get the right idea at the beginning?

Problem 0.2, Page 18:

> Construct an explicit deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$ onto $S^{n−1}$.

Consider
$$f_t: X \to X, t \in I, f_t(x) = (1-t)x + t \frac{x}{|x|}.$$

Hence, $f_0 = \mathbb{I}$,  $f_1 = \frac{x}{|x|}$, and $f_t|_{S^{n-1}} = S^{n-1}$ for all $t$.

Comment: Well, does it work?

Comment: Yes I find it work, Dear @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez....

Comment: So what are you asking, really? :-)

Comment: Trying to figure out if @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez still wants to talk to me...?

Comment: Don't you mean $f_t(x) = tx + (1-t)\frac{x}{|x|}$?

Comment: @Neal Maybe $\Bbb I$ means $x\mapsto x$?

Comment: Yes, thank you @PeterTamaroff. I am following Hatcher's notation.

Comment: @Jellyfish Strikes me as odd.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff That's what I guessed too. It seems to me that it should be written either $f_t = t\mathbb{I} + (1-t)(x\mapsto x/|x|)$ or $f_t(x) = tx + (1-t)(x/|x|)$.

Comment: @Neal Thanks, I think yours is a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct. What you could do additionally is to argue why $f\mid_{S^{n-1}}=id$ for all $t$. It can be argued as follows: if $x \in S^{n-1}$ then $x = {x \over |x|}$ and therefore $f(x) = (1-t)x + tx = x$.